# Boostrap modal-backdop issue (JavaScript needed)

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

I have some issues with Bootstrap modal. When I click to open a modal, it's seems good, but when I close modal it's all black. I noticed that when I click x (close), at the end of code I have 5 of this classes `<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>`.

Here is the code of modal:

```
<div class="modal fade product-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title product-title">
                    {{$prod_name}}
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="product-description">
                    {{$product->description}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's in PHP foreach.

Full code: [pastebin.com/uZHYqqBu](https://pastebin.com/uZHYqqBu) (first modal starts from line 221 and second from line 286).

Comment: Can you add your modal before closing body tag </body>?

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible. It's in php foreach so i can't remove it, must stay where it is.

Comment: If you can paste the full source code  with php loop that would be better to understand the situation.

Comment: Well if you want full code, pastebin.com/uZHYqqBu. This is it, first modal starts from 221 and secound 286.

Comment: I think you need to have separate instance of modal, currently in your loop it is creating the same instance of all of them as a result when you click to close it is just closing one but still remains others

Comment: Yes, so any advice what i have to edit?

Comment: what you need to do is that when you are looping you need to add dyanmic id for your modal and also target that id in your button like: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button> and <div class="modal fade" id="myModal"

Comment: so myModal will be dynamically handle using your loop index example echo 'myModal'.$i

Comment: let me know if you don't understand what I mentioned

Comment: You could try to remove the foreach, get the required data for the modal on open with ajax. Just pass the id of the object you want to retrieve to the modal and make an http request to your backend. Or, inject the data with javascript to your modal. You can do this with VueJS. Look it up, there are many tutorials on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the whole modal code inside the foreach then you will have multiple instances of modal element so the functionalities in bootstrap will not work properly since these functionalities are designed for targeting single instance of element.

So, to solve this you have to keep the modal code out of the foreach block and have to populate the data in the modal dynamically on a click event.